# Multisite login and redirect to users main blog,

Tags: multisite, redirect, wp-login-form

On the multisite main page (http://example.com/) I have a login-form where users can login to their multisite like so:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'redirect' => get_active_blog_for_user(),
);

wp_login_form( $args );
?>
```

After logging in they will be redirected to their dashboard (http:// example.com/userblog/wp-admin/). I don't want them to be redirected to their dashboard. I want them to be redirected to their mainpage instead (http://example.com/userblog/). How can I achieve this?

Kind regards
Johan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this and I only use:

```
wp_login_form();
```

Since I don't want users to get access to the wp-admin area at all I use the following code:

```
// Restrict users from accessing the admin-area
function restrict_admin()
{
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_sites' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( site_url() );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'restrict_admin', 1 );

// Disable admin-bar for users
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');

function remove_admin_bar() {
    if (!current_user_can('manage_sites') && !is_admin()) {
        show_admin_bar(false);
    }
}
```

Kind regards
Johan

Answer (score -1):

And what if you have a custom link and you want your users to be redirected there?
I used "clean login" plugin and users are redirected to the custom link, but not of their sites.
Example i want them to be redirected to www.site.com/user-page/custom-dashboard

But with clean login or others plugins I can only get them to www.site.com/custom-dashboard

So I can not redirect them from the main site to their sites